# Doctrine - How to show a Collection property and choose which field to get

Tags: symfony, doctrine, query-builder

I have 2  entities `User` and `Post` linked with a One-To-Many relationship.

I am writting a query with the queryBuilder to extract needed user details and some info about the posts of the given user :

```
return $this->createQueryBuilder('u')
            ->select('u.id AS userId, u.username, u.email, u.createdAt, u.roles ')
            ->leftjoin('u.posts', 'p')
            ->select('p.description, p.postPic')
            ->andWhere('u.id = :id')
            ->setParameter('id', $id)
            ->getQuery()
            ->getResult()
        ;
```

The result is obviously something like that:

```
[
    {
        "userId": 1,
        "username": "Toto",
        "email": "toto@example.com",
        "createdAt": "2024-02-22T16:13:06+01:00",
        "roles": [],
        "description": "super Post from Toto",
        "postPic": "https://images.pexels.com/photos/8159657/pexels-photo-8159657.jpeg"
    },
    {
        "userId": 1,
        "username": "Toto",
        "email": "toto@example.com",
        "createdAt": "2024-02-22T16:13:06+01:00",
        "roles": [],
        "description": "another Super Post from Toto",
        "postPic": "https://images.pexels.com/photos/8159657/pexels-photo-8159657.jpeg"
    }
]
```

but what I would like to reach is:

```
[
    {
        "userId": 1,
        "username": "Toto",
        "email": "toto@example.com",
        "createdAt": "2024-02-22T16:13:06+01:00",
        "roles": [],
        "posts": [
            {
                "description": "super Post from Toto",
                "postPic": "https://images.pexels.com/photos/8159656/pexels-photo-8159656.jpeg"
            },
            {
                "description": "another Super Post from Toto",
                "postPic": "https://images.pexels.com/photos/8159657/pexels-photo-8159657.jpeg"
            },
        ]
    }
]
```

I am searching a way to show a Collection property like it is when there is no `select` with `createQueryBruilder()` but with a `select` to be able to choose which field to get from the entity.

Does anyone have a suggestion on the best way to do it please?

Comment: Have you seen this [Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/66918036/11239251) ? As stated, doctrine returns flat arrays and you may need a custom mapper or you may use [Doctrine Native SQL](https://www.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine-orm/en/2.8/reference/native-sql.html)